# how can I check the given keys age and remove them if <16

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help figuring out to have this fuction return only the people who are 16 and older.

```
function getNamesOfLegalDrivers(people) {

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 14 },
  { name: 'Joey', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 18 }
];
```

`console.log(getNamesOfLegalDrivers(examplePeopleArray))` should be `["Joey", "Jane"]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` function of Array interface.

```js
result = people.filter((item) => item.age >= 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter function to get the result

```
var result = examplePeopleArray.filter(x=> x.age >= 16);
```

This way you will get the filter value from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use map to get the desired output.

```
function getNamesOfLegalDrivers(people) { 
    return people.map(p => {
        if(p.age >= 16){
            return p.name;
        }
    }
}
```